# Read HTML as Unicode with Python Mechanize

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am having troubles getting python mechanize to return unicode strings as opposed to type `str` in Python 2.7.6.

```
url = 'http://www.huffingtonpost.com'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
html = br.open(url).read()
print(type(html))
print(BeautifulSoup(html).original_encoding)
```

The html is type str, but the original encoding of the page as detected by beautiful soup and as you can see if you look at the source code for the page is utf8, i.e. unicode. Is there a way for the browser to get the html (and subsequent text extracted from the html) as unicode? The one solution I've come across is to decode the html back to unicode, i.e. `html.decode('utf8')`, but it seems bizarre that the page needs to be converted to `str` and then back to unicode. Is there a way to get the html as encoded by the site with the mechanize browser?

Comment: You are conflating Unicode and UTF-8. The page is encoded in UTF-8 and you have to decode on input -- which is what you were doing -- to Unicode. Then, on output, you encode the Unicode to UTF-8.